# No period in first part of regular expression

Tags: regex, gmail, spam

This is what I'm currently working with:
`((?i)(\w|^){0,25}[0-9]{3})[^\.]*@(gmail)\.com`

What I'm attempting to do is block any email that is any amount of characters but with 3 numbers trailing the characters.

This works. HOWEVER, when Google creates a username for people, it usually chooses `firstname.lastname###@gmail.com`. I don't want an email with a period before the @gmail.com to be included.

I have played and played with this expression, and I can't get it. So for example `john.doe123@gmail.com`, the expression is tagging everything after the period. I need for the regex to check the ENTIRE email and check to see if it follows the expression. I know there is this tidbit `^[^\.]*$` but I have no idea where to put it.

Comment: Do yo mean like this? `^\w{0,25}[0-9]{3}@gmail\.com$` https://regex101.com/r/suDBVm/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match 0-25 word characters followed by 3 digits `\w{0,25}[0-9]{3}` and use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string.

```
^\w{0,25}[0-9]{3}@gmail\.com$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/suDBVm/1)

If you want to make use of the [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^` you could match 0-25 times matching any char except a whitespace char, @ or a dot followed by 3 digits using `[^\s@.]{0,25}[0-9]{3}`

```
^[^\s@.]{0,25}[0-9]{3}@gmail\.com$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AzxpyT/1)

Comment: That did the trick!  I was dreading mulling over this more this morning, but you certainly came to the rescue!